# How do I resolve the error "No module found" from tensorflow / keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, modulenotfounderror

I am running python script in Jupyter-lab.
The following is my code:

```py
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

The error is:

> No module named 'tensorflow.keras.layers'; 'tensorflow.keras' is not a package"**

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Linux?

Without knowing the version of everything you are using...

1. Try `pip3 install` instead of just `pip install`. Also, consider installing the packages with Conda instead, or with pip if you installed with Conda.
2. Wherever you type 'Python' try Python3 or Python3.6 or Python3.7, etc. I don't know your setup, but try different versions of Python if you type the word 'Python' anywhere.
3. Speaking of virtual environments: Jupyter can out of nowhere start having problems finding your virtual environment. Make sure Jupyter is using the env you created for the venture.
4. Try creating a new virtual environment. Also, if you are in a virtual environment with Virtualenv try Conda instead or vice versa. Remember what I said about specifying the Python version here too.

I always have to do this dance with all these packages when I'm using Tensorflow or Pytorch.
Lastly, I have to ask if you've just tried restarting your computer.